# How to get source branch from google cloud build trigger on push when merging

Tags: github, google-cloud-platform, continuous-deployment, google-cloud-build

I am merging 'feature-branch' onto 'dev-branch' from a github pull request. I am using a google cloud build trigger that is triggered on push to 'dev-branch'. From what I can tell in the [documentation of substitution variables](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/configuring-builds/substitute-variable-values), there are no substitution variables to get the name of the branch that I am merging from - 'feature-branch' and only the branch that I merging to - 'dev-branch'. Is there a way or a workaround to get information (name, sha, id, etc.) of the branch that is being merged from on a google cloud build trigger from a push to branch event?

Comment: If this FR is implemented this would be trivial: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/236014017

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presumably you can have some naming conventions on the first line of the commit message (happens at `merge pull request` "event"), so that this line includes the source (or `head`) branch name (the source of the merge - in your words - 'feature-branch').

Then, you can create a substitution variable:

```
substitutions:
  _COMMIT_MESSAGE: $(commit.commit.message)
```

here is a documentation link: [Creating substitutions using payload bindings](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/configuring-builds/use-bash-and-bindings-in-substitutions#creating_substitutions_using_payload_bindings)

And use that variable in some build step to get the the `head` branch name:

```
    mapfile -t commit_lines <<< "${_COMMIT_MESSAGE}"
    source_branch="$(echo ${commit_lines[0]} | <<add your command here following naming convention for the commit message>> )"
    echo "=> My source branch name: ${source_branch}"
```

After that you can use the source branch name.